# How to make index name to resolve dynamically

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Index name will be derived at run time like say id_t1_t2 based on some field
How can i make the index name dynamic in 
@Document(indexname="",type="news")

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could simply use an alias.
I am creating one index a day, named `my-index-[date]` covered by an alias named `my-index`.

This gives :

```
@Document(indexname="my-index",type="news")
```

Note that some repository's functions won't work, like `findOne(Object)`, instead you will want to use a custom `findBy[...]` method.